# Population equation in ODE and PDE looks and solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, heat-equation

In one of the Differential equation book says the following:

The  ODE population equation is $dp/dt = p$....(1)

and the general solution of the above cited equations is: $p(t) = ce^t$. ...(2)

Solving of (1) is nothing but integration. But, after integrating the (1), I dint get (2). How (2) is solution of (1). I am wrong or text book wrong?

Also, the PDE of population equation look like $u_t$= $u$ ....(3), where $u$ is in $x$ and $t$. Now as per the same text book, the general solution of (3) is $u_(x,t)$ $= F(x) e^t$. ...(4).
In (4), where we got F(x) and prove it (4) is solution of (3) as well as (2) is solution of (1).

Regards.

Comment: What?  Just take the derivative and you see 2 has to be true.  Do the same thing for 3,4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a little deduction to get (2) from (1).

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l}
\frac{dp}{dt}=p\\
\frac{dp}{p}=dt\\
\mbox{By integrating for each sides:}\\
\int\frac{dp}{p}=\int dt\\
\ln p=t+C\quad \mbox{where $C$ is a constant to be determined}\\
p=e^Ce^t\\
p=C_0e^t\quad\mbox{where $C_0=e^C$ is also a constant}
\end{array}
\end{equation}
You can get (4) from (3) by the same method but you should view $x$ as a constant when you do the analysis (say, integral) in $t$.

For the sake of simplicity, I use a alternative method, say integral factor, to solve (3). Note the integral factor of (3) is $e^{-t}$. By multiplying the factor on each sides of (3), we have
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}e^{-t}-u e^{-t}=0\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(e^{-t}u)=0\\
\end{equation}
Integrate each side of above equation in $t$, and note u is function of both $x$ and $t$, we have:
\begin{equation}
\int \frac{\partial}{\partial t}(e^{-t}u) dt=\int 0 dt\\
e^{-t}u=F(x)\quad\mbox{(*)}\\
u=F(x)e^t
\end{equation}
where $F(x)$ is a function to be determined. I should point out that $F(x)$ appear in (*) because $u$ is a function of both $x$ and $t$. So when we integrate the both side of equation in $t$, there must have a function of $x$ instead of a constant. (In the case of ODE, such as the previous example, there is a constant $C$ after indefinite integral.) In other word, if we compute derivative of (*) on each sides in $t$, we can get the original equation. That is,
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} e^{-t} u=\frac{\partial}{\partial t} F(x)\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}e^{-t}-u e^{-t}=0\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=u\\
\end{equation}
The derivative of $F(x)$ in $t$ is zero because it is a function of $x$ and independent of $t$.

Comment: ! I dint get (4) from (3) as this is not like ODE. Can you do this. Please

Comment: @how we will get F(x) in solution. Please show me, getting (4) from (3).

Comment: I am so sorry that I have just received your comments. I have rewrite my answer for your new question.

Comment: Lion! you are really lion in Mathematics. I am so thankful to your wonderful explanation. There is no words to describe your help. Many many thanks. I have some small doubt, how to get or obtain Integral factors? is there any common formula to find integral factor of any function?

Comment: Indeed, there are a lot of formulas to find integral factor. And it is depend on construction of equation. But I do not remember them exactly. You can find them in references about ODE. BTW, although there are many formulas to find them, I usually compute them by intuition, say to add or time some items and then use formula such as multiplication derivative etc.. It is more convenient than using formulas in most time.

Comment: ! well, in your solution, please find derivative of (*) and show me the original equation. Please see the (*) in your solution please.

Comment: I have add it in my answer.

Comment: ! thank you and bye bye